# TCPDF content grouping - prevent section from being on different page

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF and using the writeHTML function to create PDF's like this:

```
$html = 'html content';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

I have sections of content and each section is in a div and table, as the page and content automatically continues over to the next page, sometimes i get a very few lines of my content on one page and the remaining on the next page.

Is there a way in TCPDF, to tell it to make sure that the entire content of a div or table should be together? so if it needs to go to the next page, it should take the entire div to the next page?

Thanks

*** UPDATE ***

As olger suggested, 'page-break-inside' style attribute seems to work and do the job below:

```
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
HTML grouped content
</div>
```

Comment: Is the amount of content in the divs/tables always the same or are they for example dynamically generated from another source, so they differ in amount every time?

Comment: olger, yes they are dynamically generated so they differ every time

Comment: Maybe you should look into using the 'page-break-inside' style attribute, [as shown in the first answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738638/how-to-control-page-breaks-in-tcpdf). This would require you to change your source HTML instead of PHP.

Comment: Awesome, just tried it and seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want breakable text then add this style div or table which you used. Add this style in your code style="page-break-inside:avoid;"

Comment: Please read the [code formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for reference on how to improve the readability of this and future answers.